# ¿Es posible centrar el texto de ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbar

Quería saber si es posible centrar el texto de ActionBar, por defecto viene a la izquierda.

Por defecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Centrada (Así es como me gustaría poner):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible? Gracias!

Edito 2:

MainActivity.java

```
package prueba.otrointento;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btn1;
    ImageButton btn2;
    ImageButton btn3;
    ImageButton btn4;
    ImageButton btn5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(boton1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton2);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton3);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main5Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton5);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="prueba.otrointento">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="Prueba1"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main3Activity"
            android:label="Prueba2"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main4Activity"
            android:label="Prueba3"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main5Activity"
            android:label="Diseño Gráfico"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="236dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/des_1"
            android:id="@+id/des_1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/des_2"
            android:id="@+id/des_2"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="236dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/des_3"
            android:id="@+id/des_3"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="236dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/des_4"
            android:id="@+id/des_4"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    android:minHeight="73dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:elevation="0dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/btn1_puls_1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_des1_puls"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn3"
    android:src="@drawable/btn2_puls_2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_rep1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/btn3_puls_2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_sm1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn4"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn3"
    android:src="@drawable/btn4_puls_2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_ip1" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn5"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn5_puls_2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_dg1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn4" />
```

Log error:

```
12-18 17:49:18.665 1604-1604/prueba.otrointento E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: prueba.otrointento, PID: 1604
                                                                    Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, iconPack:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, fontPkg:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk}
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{prueba.otrointento/prueba.otrointento.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at prueba.otrointento.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

Comment: Que sistema operativo? Como estas trabajando la app? Hibrida, nativa? Agrega tu codigo

Comment: Android, he añadido al primer mensaje el androidmanifest y mainactivity.java, dime si hace falta algo más, gracias

Comment: Deja tambien el layout que ocupas

Comment: añadido @sioesi

Comment: Te deje respuesta con dos opciones que deberian funcionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<p align=center>Diseño</p>"));
```

**EDICION**

Intenta con esto, es un custom layout , en el fondo lo que haces es definir de manera particular como sera tu ActionBar y en este caso, un TextView que sera tu titulo y centrado como tu lo quieres.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Aqui te dejo el layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Diseño grafico"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Funciona! Así es como yo tenía antes el botón atrás, así que imagino que lo borro del manifest ya, el problema es que al poner la flecha deja demasiado espacio hacia la derecha y el texto ya no queda tan centrado, queda casi a la derecha, habría que moverlo un poco hacía la izquierda

Comment: Añadiendo android:layout_marginRight se soluciona! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Me lo has solucionado a la perfección.

Comment: Hecho, gracias!!!

Answer (score 4):

#### Como centrar un titulo en un Toolbar.

La forma de realizar esto es mediante la propiedad `android:layout_gravity` de la vista que contendrá el titulo, en este caso el `TextView`.

Esta propiedad debe ser definida como "center", esto para que el texto quede perfectamente centrado.

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Ejemplo :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Titulo del Toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

De esta forma tu titulo quedaría perfectamente centrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Siempre me inclino por esta forma :)